# Text not showing on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on creating a website which uses images which, when hovered over, displays a short line of text. This would be similar to what is done on the [nowthisnews.com](http://nowthisnews.com) website.

However, I cannot get this to work properly.

Here is a snippet of what I have got so far:

```css
  #facebook-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  
  #facebook {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  #facebook:hover + #facebook-menu {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="footer"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
        <br>
        <ul class="list-inline">
          <div class="hover">
            <img href="" id="facebook" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/square-facebook-128.png" height="39px" width="39px"></div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="facebook-menu">
    <font size=5><b>Geeky Pixel</b>
              <br><font size=2>
              Get all news and updates directly to your Facebook feed.<font size=5>
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Please note: Coding is not my strong point. There are probably many errors here.

Comment: just do this with js, I will make a codepen for this in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a issue in the markup. In order use `+` `#facebook-menu` should be a sibling of `#facebook`. I cleaned up the markup.

**Below code should work**

```css
  #facebook-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  
  #facebook {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  #facebook:hover + #facebook-menu {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="footer"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
       
            <img href="" id="facebook" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/square-facebook-128.png" height="39px" width="39px">

            <div id="facebook-menu">
                <b>Geeky Pixel</b>
                <p>Get all news and updates directly to your Facebook feed.</p>
            </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have done a much smoother implementation using Jquery, people will say jWuery is not needed for hover functionality, however, doing it with JS gives better cross browser consistency and definitely more options.

```
$('#facebook').mouseenter(function()
{$('#facebook-menu').removeClass('puffOut').addClass('puffIn magictime');});

$('#facebook-menu').mouseleave(function()
{$('#facebook-   menu').removeClass('puffIn').addClass('puffOut');});
```

I have used Jquery here instead of JS, because there are some buggy js behaviours when adding and removing classes with plain js.

Link to pen:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/YWaWJE

I have removed some of your css and added some keyframe animations.